# coxme and behavioural data

Tags: r, mixed-models, cox-regression

I have behavioural data (latencies, i.e., time until an individual did a certain behaviour) that I am trying to model with a coxme (mixed cox regression) with the latency as a response, test as an explanatory variable, and ID as a random effect.  I choose the coxme because there are many latencies capped at 20 minutes (i.e., individual did not do the behaviour within 20 minute observation).

I've only been able to find examples for a coxme regression with a survival curve as the response, so I'm not sure how to adapt this model to my data.

At present, I've tried the following, and received an error:

```
coxme(latency ~ tests + (1|ID), data = df)
Error in if (n == 0) stop("No observations remain in the data set") : 
  argument is of length zero
```

How do I get this to work?

EDIT: updated with an example dataset.  Note, all latency values are > 0 and capped at 20.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(c(LETTERS[1:20]),each=4),
                 tests = rep(letters[1:4], replace = FALSE),
                 time = abs(rnorm(80, mean = 10, sd = 4)),
                 latency = ifelse(time > 20, 20, time))
```

Comment: It's really heard to say what's going wrong without any data. Can you share part of the data, or provide some information on the structure of the data? Because it seems like none of your observations pass the initial filters.

Comment: @slamballais thanks for the suggestion.  I've updated my question with a small example dataset that crudely approximates my data.